# FiddlerCore: how to use system proxy right?

Tags: proxy, fiddlercore

I want to sniff some https traffic of a browser. My network settings use the proxy configuration "Use  automatic configuration script: 'http://proxyconf-domain.net/'"

Now my code looks like this:

```
FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplicationOnAfterSessionComplete;

FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);

...

private void FiddlerApplicationOnAfterSessionComplete(Session oSession)
{
    if (oSession.LocalProcessID == 22228)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chrome Traffic");
    }
}
```

**Problem:** After Startup my system proxy settings are lost so the browser cannot connect to internet and i have to reset them manually. But i want FiddlerCore to work like the Fiddler App.

The FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default has the RegisterAsSystemProxy flag. The Fiddler App has the same settings: 
[FiddlerSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxneT.png)
But the Fiddler App is capturing the traffic and the browser keeps its proxy settings.

Do I have to read the system proxy and set it in my code for FiddlerCore or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After Startup my system proxy settings are lost so the browser cannot connect to internet and i have to reset them manually. But i want FiddlerCore to work like the Fiddler App.

This is because you have not called `Shutdown()` method when your program exits. Call `Shutdown()` to tell FiddlerCore to stop listening on the specified port, and 
unregister as the **system proxy**. For example:

```
    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplicationOnAfterSessionComplete;
    FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
    ...

    //when your program exits
    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    ...
```

In many cases, you're better off simply calling `Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.oProxy.Detach()`.